# How to Select same column in 1 table twice in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can i select 1 column twice using only 1 table, the problem is i have to separate 1 column into 2 return

ex: table Logs

```
TIMELOGS   11:00 , 12:12 , 13:00 , 17:01 , 17:05 , 17:10

TIMEMODE     0    ,   0     ,  0    ,   1    ,   1     ,   1
```

the output should be

```
IN   11:00 , 12:12 , 13:00

OUT   17:01, 17:05 , 17:10
```

How can I combine these to queries

```
Select TIMELOGS as IN FROM table_logs where TIMEMODE = 0;
```

and

```
Select TIMELOGS as OUT FROM table_logs where TIMEMODE = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to enumerate the 0s and the 1s and then group by that:

```
select max(case when mode = 0 then time end),
       max(case when mode = 1 then time end)
from (select l.*,
             (@rn := if(@m = mode, @rn + 1,
                        if(@m := mode, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from logs l cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @m := -1) params
      order by mode, time
     ) l
group by rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

To output the format you described, (suppose you're using MySQL) you could do:

```
select 
  case when TIMEMODE = 0 then 'IN' else 'OUT' end,
  group_concat(TIMELOGS)
from table_logs
group by TIMEMODE
```